# How to find in Linux system, which suitable version of glibc can be installed

Tags: linux, glibc, gentoo

I'm trying to update glibc 2.19-r1 to newer version 2.23-r1 in order to overcome some security vulnerabilities. I generated a new binary package (tbz2) using Gentoo system, but now I'm having problems with installing it to my system.

my question is: How can I know if there is anther feature/application that also needs to be updated? Which dependencies does glibc has?

Thank you,
Sami

Comment: 'glibc' *is* your OS ( together with the kernel ), and a change from 2.19 to 2.23 may break your OS.

Comment: @KnudLarsen what is the distribution you are attempting to upgrade? Is it also a Gentoo system?

Comment: You appear to have jumped to conclusion: "missing dependencies" when your problem is likely *elsewhere*. You should describe "problems with installing" you are having in some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

> Which dependencies does glibc has?

It doesn't have *any*.

When configured, it may require a minimal kernel version on which it would run. Usually it supports kernels that are newer than at least 5 years; on `x86` often much older kernels are also supported.

To *build* it, you also need sufficiently recent versions of `gcc`, `make` and some other tools (but these dependencies don't transitively apply to the system on which you want to *install* it).